# Content Providers or direct database?

Tags: android

I was wondering whether we can use the databases like (contacts.db, mmssms.db) directly instead of content providers ?

I have a reason to ask so. In my recent project, I was supposed develop a contact app. I used content provider for contact management. As I have learnt via content providers, I can query only table at a time via URIs, there is no way (at least, I didn't find) to join two tables and then get a query resolved.

And I had read, that databases are only visible to the applications that originally created them, so do my app would be able to access these databases ?

I am just a hobby developer for my own phone. I have no intention to make an app that directly uses the databases. I can pull the database from device, analyse them via sqlite. It is not that I am up against the content providers or they don't suit my need write now, it is just that it can be done or not ?

Any opinions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Providers give you a lot more than just database access. Being able to use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) to automatically reload your data (and update your UI) when the underlying data changes can vastly simplify your applications.

The goal of Content Providers is more to create a single, controlled layer for accessing your data. There is nothing stopping you from creating a custom URI that joins multiple tables together and returns the resulting joined result.

Comment: Convinced so far.
It would have been hell to manage the complicated contact database without less complicated contact content provider.

Comment: How do I create a custom URI to join multiple tables and return data ?

Comment: @GauravTiwari - if you are writing your own content provider, you can provide whatever URIs you want for querying. My recommendation is to make a separate URI specific to any join you need (i.e., say you have a /task URI and a /group URI - make a /task_group URI that combines information from both).

If you are using SQLiteQueryBuilder, then you can use setTables to do your join (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables(java.lang.String) has an example)

Comment: Well, I am trying to use contacts content provider ? Then ?

Comment: @GauravTiwari - remember, a Content Provider is like a public API. If they don't give it to you, then you'll need to do it yourself. If are creating content associated with contacts, then you should insert it into the contacts content provider and query it alongside any other data.